# I see this error when run my app type 'string' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index' flutter when I using http

Tags: flutter, http, dart

when I want to get a value from a json form in flutter, i face this error it says

```
type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'
```

and Im using `http: ^0.13.4`
and this is my code

```
void getData() async{

  Response res=await get("https://something.com");
  String dat=res.body;
  var datta=jsonDecode(dat)['title'];

  print(datta);

  }
```

how can I fix this problem?

Comment: You JSON almost certainly is an array (i.e. it starts and ends with `[` and `]`), so trying to index it with `title` doesn't work (because that would only work if it were a JSON 'object' (i.e. with `{}` around it). Update the question showing the actual JSON.

Comment: thanks a lot , I do that.

Answer (score 0):

dont forget to write Uri.parse

```
void getData() async{

  Response res=await get(Uri.parse("https://something.com"));
  String dat=res.body;
  var datta=jsonDecode(dat)['title'];

  print(datta);

  }
```

Answer (score -1):

You should handle the request in this way, worked for me:

```
void getData() async {
  String baseUrl = "something.com";
  String endpoint = "/your/endpoint";
  
  Uri url = Uri.https(baseUrl, endpoint, {});

  http.Response response = await http.get(url);

  // Error handling
  // if (response.statusCode != "200") {
  //   sendError();
  // }

  String stringBody = response.body;
}
```

Then you convert the string into a JSON object using dart:convert library:

```
import "dart:convert";

// Json object
Map<String, dynamic> jsonVar = json.decode(stringBody) as Map<String, dynamic>;
```

That should be enough, but I suggest you to implement a model class to handle your response, and another model to handle the kind of object you are working with (e.g. Book, Post, Product, etc).